# How to avoid loading screen at closing interstitial ads (Using AssetManager - Libgdx)

Tags: android, libgdx, ads

I am developing a game using libgdx. Resources are managed with AssetManager.

As indicated in [Libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager#Resuming_with_a_Loading_Screen), Managed OpenGL resources like Textures need to be reloaded.

So, in my ApplicationListener # resume () method I switch to loading screen and call AssetManager # update () again.

Now I'm implementing some ads.

The problem that I have is that if I show an interstitial ad. When this ad is closed and I return to the game, the loading screen appears again and takes some time which is annoying.

(I've integrated Ads to my Libgdx Android code following this guide: [Libgdx ads](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx))

Any ideas? Thanks!!

this is my code:

```
public class MyGame extends Game implements InputProcessor {    

public Assets assets;
public SpriteBatch sb;
public Screen ScrSplash;
public Screen ScrLoading;
public Screen ScrMainMenu;  

public IActivityRequestHandler myRequestHandler;        

public GamPrincipal(IActivityRequestHandler handler) {  
    myRequestHandler = handler;
}   

@Override
public void create() {      
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    ScrSplash       = new ScrSplash(this, sb);
    ScrLoading      = new ScrLoading(this, sb);
    ScrMainMenu     = new ScrMainMenu (this, sb);
    assets = new Assets();      
    setScreen(ScrSplash);
}
```

//====

```
public class ScrMyScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{

private MyGame game;    
private OrthographicCamera camara;
private SpriteBatch sb;             
private Sprite sprBackground;
//…more…//

public ScrMyScreen(MyGame game, SpriteBatch sb) {       
    this.game = game;
    this.sb = sb;
}   

@Override
public void render(float delta) {       
      sb.begin();    
        sprBackground.draw(sb);
            /// 
                //…more…//
    sb.end();
}   


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) { 
}

@Override
public void show() {            
    sprFondo             = game.assets.sprBackground;
    sprLblTitle          = game.assets.sprTitle;
        //…more…//


    //**************Show Ads*******************
    game.myRequestHandler.showAds(true);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {       
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    //Show loading screen   
    game.setScreen(game.ScrLoading);        
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    //Call Dispose assets method
}
```

//===

```
public class ScrLoading implements Screen {

private MyGame game;
private Sprite sprBG;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch sb;
//… 

public ScrLoading(GamPrincipal juego, SpriteBatch sb) {     
    this.game = game;
    this.sb = sb;   
}   

@Override
public void render(float delta) { 

    if(Recursos.manager.update()) { 
            game.setScreen(game. ScrMyScreen); 
    }       

   sb.begin();     
        sprBG.draw(sb);
    //…more… (draw text : “loading…”  )  
        //  
   sb.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {        
    texture = new Texture("data/images/bg.png");    
    sprBG = new Sprite (texture);
    Assets.manager.update();
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    //Call Dispose assets method
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AssetManager, you don't have to reload your Assets. It caches them automaticaly. So just delete that line in resume.

Comment: I deleted that line. Now a black screen appears for an instant (about 1 sec) after close ad. This happens with banner ads and offer wall. With interstitial ads not happen. I don´t know why. But now it's not annoying. Thanks!